# Error while getting current user id

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

I am running through a minor problem that I cannot solve.
Yesod with postgres template.

My goal is to create a new directory named after current uid.

```
-- model
-- User
     ident Text
--   ...

-- Handler
uploadDirectory :: FilePath
uploadDirectory = "static/docs"

writeToServer :: FileInfo -> Handler FilePath
writeToServer file = do
    let filename = unpack $ fileName file
        filepath = registerFilePath filename
    liftIO $ fileMove file filepath
    return filename

registerFilePath :: String -> FilePath
registerFilePath f = do
    (_,muser) <- requireAuthPair
    uploadDirectory </> showText (userIdent muser) </> f
```

I get:

```
*"Couldn't match type ‘AuthEntity (HandlerSite [])’ with ‘User’
Expected type: [(AuthId (HandlerSite []), User)]
Actual type: [(AuthId (HandlerSite []), AuthEntity (HandlerSite []))]"*
```

It seems that calling userIdent requires muser to be of Persistent type 'User'.
However requireAuthPair returns an AuthEntity (HandlerSite []).

I guess requireAuthPair is not defined for this situation. Any help?

Yours faithfully,
Felipe Argolo

PS: I did not alter the postgres template authentication settings.
I'm testing with dummy authenticantion first

Answer (score 1):

Looking specifically at:

```
registerFilePath :: String -> FilePath
registerFilePath f = do
    (_,muser) <- requireAuthPair
    uploadDirectory </> showText (userIdent muser) </> f
```

The type signature of this doesn't look right. You're saying that you're returning a *pure* `FilePath` value, but in fact it should be wrapped up in some monadic type, e.g. `String -> Handler FilePath`. You'd also likely need to add a `return $` before the `uploadDirectory`.

Comment: "Looking specification at" <- Seems like a typo